# Getting data from input to send to whatsapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input, whatsapp

There is a script that sends a message to whatsapp

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // URL for the POST /message request
    var url = 'https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********';
    var data = {
      phone: '***********', // Recipient's phone number
      body: 'There should be a message here', // Message
    };
    // Send a request when the button is clicked
    $(".button").click(function() {
      $.ajax(url, {
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST'
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And there are inputs that are filled in by the client to send information about the order to connected partners (cafes, restaurants) by phone number in whatsapp for order formation and delivery

```html
<input name="name" class="t-input">
<input name="phone" class="t-input">
<input name="address" class="t-input">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="78888888888"> //Phone number of the recipient of order information in whatsapp
```

Now the task is to send information about the order to whatsapp, which is contained in the input values (name, phone,address) to the recipient's number (recipient) and put names before each input value (except recipient), i.e. Name:, phone Number:, Address: from a new line. The recipient value must be inserted in phone, and the other input values (name,phone,address) must be inserted in data.

Example of a received message:

- Name: Alex
- Phone: +79999999999
- Address: Kazan, Baumana street, the house 20, apartment 19
- Order: Pizza " Margarita"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need grab the value from the form items, and compose a body value.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Send a request when the button is clicked
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $.ajax('https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********', {
      data: JSON.stringify({
        phone: $('input[name="recipient"]').val(),
        body: 
        `Name: ${$('input[name="name"]').val()}\n`+
        `Phone: ${$('input[name="phone"]').val()}\n`+
        `Address: ${$('input[name="address"]').val()}\n`+
        `Order: Pizza " Margarita"`
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      type: 'POST'
    });
  });
});
```

*beyond the scope of the question:* adding validation.

Comment: I tried your solution, thank you, but it doesn't work. Even the network event in the developer console is missing.